# android: Refresh ListView using ListAdapter and SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, refresh, listadapter, simplecursoradapter

I'm trying to refresh a ListView that uses a ListAdapter created as a SimpleCursorAdapter.

Here is my code for creating the Cursor and ListAdapter in onCreate which populates the ListView.

```
tCursor = db.getAllEntries();       

ListAdapter adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.row, tCursor,
                new String[] columns,
                new int[] {R.id.rowid, R.id.date});

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Then, I add some data to the db in another method, but I can't figure out how to refresh the ListView.  Similar questions on stackoverflow and other places mention using notifyDataSetChanged() and requery(), but neither are methods of ListAdapter or SimpleCursorAdapter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm able to get the ListView to refresh by creating a new adapter and calling setListAdapter again.

I named it adapter2 in the other method.

```
tCursor = db.updateQuery();       

ListAdapter adapter2=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.row, tCursor,
                columns,
                new int[] {R.id.rowid, R.id.date});

setListAdapter(adapter2);
```

I'm not sure why this is necessary, but it works for now.  If anyone has a better solution, I'm willing to try it.

Comment: Solved my problem too. I can use this in AsynTask as well.

Answer (score 0):

In that case I recommend  to go with custom `Adapter`, by extending the `BaseAdapter` class.

Comment: As I mentioned in the original question, notifyDataSetChanged() does not work for a ListAdapter.  The error given by Eclipse says "The method notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type ListAdapter".

Comment: Rewriting code that works is hopefully a last resort, but I'll take that into consideration.  Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

The method `notifyDataSetChanged` comes from the `SimpleCursorAdapter` parent class `BaseAdapter`. The parent implements `ListAdapter` and you should be able to pass it to your `ListView`.

Try:

```
tCursor = db.getAllEntries();       

BaseAdapter adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.row, tCursor,
            new String[] columns,
            new int[] {R.id.rowid, R.id.date});

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Then you should be able to use `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Comment: I changed the type of adapter from ListAdapter to BaseAdapter as you suggested.  The list still loads properly, but calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() doesn't refresh the ListView when I call it from another method.  Am I using this incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

You can define the adapter as a class variable if it needs to be accessed from other methods in the same class.  Then you can call `changeCursor()` to refresh the ListView.

```
public class mainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // Define the Cursor variable here so it can be accessed from the entire class.
    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_coordinator_layout)

        // Get the initial cursor
        Cursor tCursor = db.getAllEntries();       

        // Setup the SimpleCursorAdapter.
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.row,
            tCursor,
            new String[] { "column1", "column2" },
            new int[] { R.id.rowid, R.id.date },
            CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);

        // Populate the ListAdapter.
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    protected void updateListView() {
        // Get an updated cursor with any changes to the database.
        Cursor updatedCursor = db.getAllEntries();

        // Update the ListAdapter.
        adapter.changeCursor(updatedCursor);
    }
}
```

If the list view needs to be updated from methods in another class, the adapter variable should be declared `public static` instead

```
public static SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
```