# Programatically unchecking items in a dialog on Android

Tags: android, dialog

I am displaying a list with checkboxes in a dialog. The list looks something like-

```
Item 1

Item 2

All
```

with a checkbox beside each item. Now the requirements is-
If Item 1 or Item 2 or both are already checked, and All is selected, Item 1 & 2 should be unchecked.

To accomplish this, I implemented DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener 's onClick listener.

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked)
{
  if(which == 2 && isChecked)
  {
    ((AlertDialog)dialog).getListView().setItemChecked(0, false);
    ((AlertDialog)dialog).getListView().setItemChecked(1, false);
  }
}
```

But this does not work. I even tried invalidating the listview by calling Invalidate() & InvalidateViews(), but no success.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks,

Akshay

Comment: Are you sure the code within the if-statement is run? If not, you can find out by either using `Log` or debugging.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I am sure that the code executes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the checkboxes are in a list. There's been a question with the opposite situation: trying to uncheck all boxes. The solution seems to be to call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Here is the link to that question: [Uncheck all checkboxes in a custom ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312069/uncheck-all-checkboxes-in-a-custom-listview)

EDIT: Okay, I'll try again :-) Found another question about it: [android: Refresh ListView using ListAdapter and SimpleCursorAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113180/android-refresh-listview-using-listadapter-and-simplecursoradapter) Hope this helps! :-)

Comment: Thanks pecka85! Yes, the checkboxes are in a list, which is in a dialog. But the dialog's adapter is a ListAdapter which does not have a method notifyDataSetChanged. This method is provided by ArrayAdapter.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pecka85! I was also expecting this to work, but it didn't. I am sure this has something to do with the list being in a dialog. Thanks for trying!