# Android ListView update with SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

Hey i use a listview for demonstrate entries which are stored in a database. I also have a EditText element and a button which adds the content of the EditText into the Database. To bind the view to the database content i use the SimpleCursorAdapter and following populate function:

```
private void populate() {
    cursor = dbAdapter.getAllItems();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    String[] from = new String[] { DBAdapter.KEY_TASK };
    int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

    // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
    cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, from, to);
    list.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
}
```

If i added a new entry, by clicking on the button i want to refresh the listview but this only works with the populate function and not with the common adapter function `notifyDataSetChanged();`. Do i have a bug or is this the right way to refresh a listview?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985955/android-simplecursoradapter-not-updating-with-database-changes), tried the [swap cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#swapCursor(android.database.Cursor)) method, or tried just simply calling [setAdapter()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113180/android-refresh-listview-using-listadapter-and-simplecursoradapter) again?

I had a similar issue where I could not get my list to update, and what I did was just create a refreshListView() method. Now you can call this initially from your onCreate(), AND anytime a user adds something to the DB. All it does is re-bind the listview to a cursor. With all the deprecating methods (requery()), and issues with notifyDataSetChanged(), I decided this was the easiest way.

Comment: Just to mention: 'requery()' is already deprecated. [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#requery()) has a clear record on this.

Comment: I know, I didn't quite word that sentence right, re-worded it :>

Comment: Hey Jack thanks for your reply, i see that i forget to say the above code is my `populate()` function i call it in my `onCreate()` method and if i click the "Add"-Button. I only wanted to know whether this is a good solution to call this method instead of calling the common `notifyDataSetChanged()` method of the base adapter class.

Comment: Oh I see, it is too early and I have not had my coffee yet. Yes that should be fine, I've been using it for awhile now and it works great.

Comment: Hehe...ok no problem sometimes i have the same problem without coffee or red bull and in fact it was my false. But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer this link...it works like charm

[Update SimpleCursorAdapter while maintaining scroll position in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255858/update-simplecursoradapter-while-maintaining-scroll-position-in-listview?rq=1)

for dynamic listview on scroll i added new item from database ..
I did mistake here ..
i was assigning new adapter for each time for same simplecursoradapter .
Instead of creating new adapter.
just use

```
adapter.changecursor(newcursorValue);
adapter.notifydatasetChanged();
 lsMedicine1.setSelectionFromTop(lsMedicine1.getLastVisiblePosition()-20, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `swapcursor()` before `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter.