# Update SimpleCursorAdapter while maintaining scroll position in ListView

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter, scroll-position

My problem: My ListView resets its scroll position to the top whenever I update its contents through its (customized) SimpleCursorAdapter.  I would like the ListView to maintain its scroll position when updated.

I started out by creating a new adapter instance every time and using `ListView.setAdapter()`, but according to [this discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/2e425f0cca0c0e8b?pli=1) I should be updating the adapter instead of resetting it.  I can't find a way to do this for SimpleCursorAdapter that works correctly.

Here are some things I've tried, omitting the method arguments:
- `SimpleCursorAdapter.changeCursorAndColumns()` with a fresh cursor successfully updates the adapter but still resets the scroll position.
- `SimpleCursorAdapter.changeCursor()` acts the same way.
- `SimpleCursorAdapter.swapCursor()` isn't available until api 11, and I am developing for api 8.
- `SimpleCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` does not update the ListView.  (Maybe there is another step I'm missing.)
- `ListView.invalidate()` does not update the ListView.
- `SimpleCursorAdapter.requery()` makes the ListView blank, and is deprecated.
- I'm familiar with the `ListView.setSelection()` solution, but I don't want my ListView to move at all when it is updated.  This snaps it to a position in the list.

This seems like it should be a common and simple problem.  Has anybody dealt with it?

Comment: See my comment below the answer.  SimpleCursorAdapter.changeCursor() does work correctly - I just had another line of code screwing things up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had a similar problem: My CursorAdapter reset the scroll position whenever the contents of the cursor changed.

I didn't realize that I actually did set a new list adapter each time the data changed. I thought the cursor himself would notify the adapter about changes to it's content but in my case it is the ContentProvider that triggers LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.onLoadFinished() in my ListFragment. In that callback I now use CursorAdapter.changeCursor() instead of creating a new adapter and everything works just fine.

I hope this helps solving your problem.

Comment: It turns out that SimpleCursorAdapter.changeCursor() works correctly.  The culprit in my case causing the listview scroll position to reset was a pair of lines of code called right before changing the cursor: `ListView.SetDivider()` and `ListView.SetDividerHeight`.  Really annoying.  I also have a `ListView.setCacheColorHint()` line in there, which does _not_ cause the scroll position to reset.

Answer (score 0):

Did the same in post execute of Async Task used following code worked for me

```
 Cursor cursor = mDataHelper.getWritableDatabase().query(
                        DataContract.Incares.TABLE_NAME,  // Table to Query
                        null, // all columns
                        null, // Columns for the "where" clause
                        null, // Values for the "where" clause
                        null, // columns to group by
                        null, // columns to filter by row groups
                        DataContract.Incares.UUID +" DESC" // sort order
                );
CursorAdapter.changeCursor(cursor);
CursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

with CursorAdapter being a global variable

Comment: Unless you have a reason for not closing the old cursor, use `CursorAdapter.changeCursor(cursor)`, not "swap"