# how to update list-view from another class in android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-listfragment

I have 2 activity, one is `ListFragmentActivity` and other is `FragmentActivity`. In ListFragmentActivity i have list-view which i want to update run-time. and FragmentActivity contains different - different view's.

I have set of data on server and through PHP web service i am trying to load all data in ListFgagmentActivity's Listview but somehow i am not able to load all data. So what i need to do is just want to update ListFragment class Listview from FragmentActivity.

I have refereed below link but the solution is not working in my case.

[How update ListView in ListFragment from FragmentActivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027202/how-update-listview-in-listfragment-from-fragmentactivity?rq=1)

I am trying to do like this:

http://android-er.blogspot.sg/2012/06/communication-between-fragments-in.html.

But insted of text-view or edit-text i want to use list-view.

Thanks in advance. Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

you can create a method to update ListView in Fragment

```
public void updateList(ArrayAdapter adapter){
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

and call it from your Activity:

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
fragment.updateList(someAdapter);
```

just don't call it in OnCreate method, because then fragment is not yet inflated.